# How to prevent function in a loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jslint

I have a jquery click function declare in for loop like this

```
for (i = 1; i !== 4; i += 1) {
    id = "index" + i + "id";
       if ($(id).length) {
          $(id).click(function() {
             var isChecked = this.checked;
             onclickHelper(isChecked, this.id);
          });
       }
}
```

How would i get rid of warning for creating function within loop? 2nd why is it bad (jslint is giving me this warning)

Comment: Giving us more code would help us fix the issue. Also you might want to call the function rather than put the block inside the IF.

Comment: `if ($(id).length)` is pointless

Comment: hi thanks the if loop is to check if the element exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $ids = $();
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    if($("#index" + i + "id").length)
        $ids = $ids.add("#index" + i + "id");

$ids.click(function () {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    onclickHelper(isChecked, this.id);
});
```

Comment: how do i know if the id exists?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you execute the expression `function() { ... }` (I do not mean calling the function), Javascript creates a separate closure for the function.
This needlessly wastes memory.

It also tempts you into making mistakes like using `i` in the function (which won't work the way you expect because Javascript doesn't have block scope).

Instead, you should put the function outside the loop – creating it only once, and storing it in a variable – then add the same function instance to every element.

Comment: Actually, **`i` will work in the function** -- even if you cache it the way JSLint wants you to.  See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUtQn/) from answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17226058/1028230).

Comment: @ruffin: Yes, but not if you call it after the loop (eg, from an event handler)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this without loop,

```
$("[id=^'index']").click(function() {
     var isChecked = this.checked;
     onclickHelper(isChecked, this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

SLaks is right, and a minimal refactor (without going into the merits of what's going on here specifically) to follow that advice would look like this:

```
/*global $, onclickHelper */
var i, id, fnCached;

// cache your function instead of creating each time in your loop
fnCached = function() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    onclickHelper(isChecked, this.id);
};

for (i = 1; i !== 4; i += 1) {
    id = "index" + i + "id";
    if ($(id).length) {
        $(id).click(fnCached());  // then simply call it
    }
}
```

As he says, JSLint simply wants you to run things more efficiently, and since you can cache functions in variables, declare outside the loop but in the same scope and *poof*, you're done.

The neat thing is that, "because" of hoisting, if you'd used `i` in function and declared `fnCached` just before the loop, the context "travels" just as if you declared in-loop, so this quick caching trick pretty much always works (though if it does make sense to declare even further up scope, do it).

```
/*jslint browser: true */
this.spam = "spam";

var i, fnCached;

fnCached = function () {
    // i's scope pervades the snippet here
    window.alert(this.spam + " " + i);
};

for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    fnCached();
}
```

So that alerts "spam 0", "spam 1", and "spam 2".

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUtQn/)